# Flask set_cookie not carrying over to other routes

Tags: python, flask, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue with the SetCookie which I can't get it to work. I've seen too many SO topics but no success so far. Here is my situation:

I have an Ajax POST call which sends a token from my frontend (JavaScript) to my backend (Flask). This Ajax call send the token to the route /sessionLogin:

```py
@app.route('/sessionLogin', methods=['POST'])
def session_login():
    id_token = request.form['idToken']   
    csrfToken = request.form['csrfToken']

    expires_in = datetime.timedelta(minutes=120)
    expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires_in
   
    session_cookie = auth.create_session_cookie(id_token, expires_in=expires_in)
   
    response = make_response(redirect('/home'))
   
    response.set_cookie(
        'session', session_cookie, expires=expires, httponly=True, secure=True)
    return response
```

Then, on any 'protected route' I am basically getting the cookie 'session':

```py
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    session_cookie = request.cookies.get('session')
    # session_cookie always returning None
    return render_template("index.html")
```

The problem is that when I sign in, get the token (from JS) and make the POST request, the request to /sessionLogin works great and I see the cookie 'session' in the response but any subsequent requests and by the way the redirect to /home does not include the cookie.

What I am missing here?

UPDATE (adding Ajax code):

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
.then(({user}) => {                   
    return user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
        console.log(user)
        if (idToken) {
            const csrfToken = getCookie('csrfToken')
            return postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/sessionLogin', idToken, csrfToken)
            .then(function() {
                console.log('logged in.')
            }, function(error) {
                window.location.assign('/login');
            })
        }
    })                    
})


const postIdTokenToSessionLogin = function(url, idToken, csrfToken) {
    // POST to session login endpoint.
    return $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: url,
      data: {idToken: idToken, csrfToken: csrfToken},
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include the Ajax code?

Comment: @JohnGordon, I've added the Ajax code. Thank you!

Comment: When you see the `session` cookie in the response, does it have a `path` attribute?

Comment: @JohnGordon, the path is set to root "/". I've tried to add the same site and domain attributes to set_cookie but didn't change the behavior :(

Comment: Are`/sessionLogin` and `/home` served from the same domain?

Comment: yes, all pages are served from same domain. Right now I am developing locally so everything running localhost.

Comment: `secure=True` means the cookie requires HTTPS, HTTPS is most likely not available on localhost, set `secure` to `False` and see if it helps.

Comment: @vremes, I've tested with response.set_cookie('session', session_cookie, expires=expires, secure=False) but no luck. Anything else I should be checking?